# How to filter 2 values in R?

Tags: r, filter, na

in my dataset, there are some null values (NA) and "tbd" values. I want to remove this 2 values. I have tried this one and didn't works.

```
train%>%
  filter(!is.na(User_Score) & User_Score!="tbd")%>%
  summarise(
    Max=max(User_Score),
    Min=min(User_Score),
    Mean=mean(User_Score),
    Median=median(User_Score),
    QUA1=quantile(User_Score,1/4),
    QUA3=quantile(User_Score,3/4),
    IQR=IQR(User_Score)
)
```

I also tried this one too, but still the same.

```
train%>%
filter(User_Score != NA & User_Score != "tbd")%>%
summarise(
 Max=max(User_Score),
 Min=min(User_Score),
 Mean=mean(User_Score),
 Median=median(User_Score),
 QUA1=quantile(User_Score,1/4),
 QUA3=quantile(User_Score,3/4),
 IQR=IQR(User_Score)
)
```

the error said:

```
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NAargument is not numeric or logical: returning NAError: Problem with `summarise()` input `QUA1`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
i Input `QUA1` is `quantile(User_Score, 1/4)`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

any ideas how to fix it? thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A column can have data of only one type. Since you have values in the data which are not numeric (`'tbd'`) the type of column is character. After removing the values convert the column to numeric and then perform the calculation.

```
library(dplyr)

result <- train%>%
  mutate(User_Score = suppressWarnings(readr::parse_number(User_Score))) %>%
  filter(!is.na(User_Score)) %>%
  summarise(
    Max=max(User_Score),
    Min=min(User_Score),
    Mean=mean(User_Score),
    Median=median(User_Score),
    QUA1=quantile(User_Score,1/4),
    QUA3=quantile(User_Score,3/4),
    IQR=IQR(User_Score)
  )
```

Comment: thankyou for answering my question, i have tried your code, but now the error is

Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `QUA1`. x missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE i Input `QUA1` is `quantile(User_Score, 1/4)`. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

what does this mean?

Comment: Some example data to debug the issue would have been helpful but I think that means there are other values in your data which are not numeric. Try the updated answer.